# How to merge default values into subarrays of a new multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge, defaults

What is the best way to define a new multidimensional array with default key/value pairs?

I think it's best explained by code sample here:

```
$defaultOptions = ['foo' => 'bar', 'another' => 'value'];
$mdArray = [
    'first' => [
        'title' => 'I am first',
        $defaultOptions,
    ],
    'second' => [
        'title' => 'I am second',
        $defaultOptions
    ]
];
```

This produces:

```
Array 
( 
    [first] => Array 
               ( 
                   [title] => I am first 
                   [0] => Array  
                          ( 
                              [foo] => bar 
                              [another] => value ) 
                          ) 
    [second] => Array 
                ( 
                    [title] => I am second 
                    [0] => Array 
                           ( 
                               [foo] => bar 
                               [another] => value 
                           ) 
                ) 
)
```

I would like the `0` key to be omitted from `$defaultOptions` in `$mdArray`, so that key/value pair would be applied to the same level as where the `$defaultOptions` is defined.

Is there a way to do it within array definition, or do I have to process this array later and append these `$defaultOptions`?

Comment: Use `array_merge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it in two ways.

**The first option is use `+` operator:**

```
$mdArray = [
    'first' => ['title' => 'I am first'] + $defaultOptions,
    'second' => ['title' => 'I am second'] + $defaultOptions
];
```

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand
>   array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the
>   left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the
>   right-hand array will be ignored.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

**The second option is use `array_merge()` function:**

```
$mdArray = [
    'first' => array_merge(['title' => 'I am first'], $defaultOptions),
    'second' => array_merge(['title' => 'I am second'], $defaultOptions)
];
```

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended. Values in the input array with numeric
>   keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in
>   the result array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Below is the updated code:

```
<?php

$defaultOptions = ['foo' => 'bar', 'another' => 'value'];
$mdArray = [
    'first' => [
        'title' => 'I am first'
    ],
    'second' => [
        'title' => 'I am second'
    ]
];

foreach($mdArray as $key => $value){
    $mdArray[$key] = array_merge($mdArray[$key], $defaultOptions);
}

print_r($mdArray);
?>
```

And here is the output:

```
Array
(
    [first] => Array
        (
            [title] => I am first
            [foo] => bar
            [another] => value
        )

    [second] => Array
        (
            [title] => I am second
            [foo] => bar
            [another] => value
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with `array_merge`:

```
$defaultOptions = ['foo' => 'bar', 'another' => 'value'];
$mdArray = [
    'first' => array_merge(['title' => 'I am first'], $defaultOptions),
    'second' => array_merge(['title' => 'I am second'], $defaultOptions),
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Purely because there wasn't a loop method with `+` posted, I'll add it.  This will add the default values to the main array via a reference variable (`&$a`).

Code:

```
$defaultOptions=['foo'=>'bar','another'=>'value'];
$mdArray = ['first'=>['title'=>'I am first'],
            'second'=>['title'=>'I am second']
];
foreach($mdArray as &$a){
    $a+=$defaultOptions;
}
var_export($mdArray);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'first' => 
  array (
    'title' => 'I am first',
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'another' => 'value',
  ),
  'second' => 
  array (
    'title' => 'I am second',
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'another' => 'value',
  ),
)
```

---

And for the record, `array_replace()` will perform this task as well (though it is a less intuitive function to call):

```
foreach($mdArray as &$a){
    $a=array_replace($a,$defaultOptions);
}
```